# upgraded from 17.10 to Ubuntu 18.04 but kernel didn't change how to fix

Tags: 17.10, 18.04, linux-headers

A few days back, I upgraded my system to 18.04. After upgrading, I did`uname -r`
it shows, Linux 4.13.0-36-generic but I am expecting it to be 4.15.

Also after the update, bootloader still shows ubuntu 17.10

So I tried upgrading manually, by following this

```
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.15/linux-headers-4.15.0-041500_4.15.0-041500.201801282230_all.deb

sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

even after rebooting, the version is shown as 4.13.

I tried checking in the advanced options in grub mode, there is no trace that 4.13 is actually installed.

why am I not able to install kernel 4.15?

The output of is `dpkg -l | grep linux`

```
ii  binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu                  2.30-15ubuntu1                              amd64        GNU binary utilities, for x86-64-linux-gnu target
ii  console-setup-linux                        1.178ubuntu2                                all          Linux specific part of console-setup
ii  libselinux1:amd64                          2.7-2build2                                 amd64        SELinux runtime shared libraries
ii  libv4l-0:amd64                             1.14.2-1                                    amd64        Collection of video4linux support libraries
ii  libv4lconvert0:amd64                       1.14.2-1                                    amd64        Video4linux frame format conversion library
ii  linux-base                                 4.5ubuntu1                                  all          Linux image base package
ii  linux-firmware                             1.173                                       all          Firmware for Linux kernel drivers
ii  linux-generic                              4.15.0.20.23                                amd64        Complete Generic Linux kernel and headers
ii  linux-headers-4.15.0-041500                4.15.0-041500.201802011154                  all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.15.0
ii  linux-headers-4.15.0-20                    4.15.0-20.21                                all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.15.0
ii  linux-headers-4.15.0-20-generic            4.15.0-20.21                                amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-4.15.7-041507                4.15.7-041507.201802280530                  all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.15.7
ii  linux-headers-generic                      4.15.0.20.23                                amd64        Generic Linux kernel headers
rc  linux-image-4.10.0-28-generic              4.10.0-28.32~16.04.2                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.10.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.10.0-42-generic              4.10.0-42.46~16.04.1                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.10.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.13.0-26-generic              4.13.0-26.29~16.04.2                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.13.0-32-generic              4.13.0-32.35                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.13.0-36-generic              4.13.0-36.40                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.13.0-37-generic              4.13.0-37.42                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.13.0-38-generic              4.13.0-38.43                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.13.0-39-generic              4.13.0-39.44                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.13.0-41-generic              4.13.0-41.46                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.15.0-20-generic              4.15.0-20.21                                amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-extra-4.10.0-28-generic        4.10.0-28.32~16.04.2                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.10.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.10.0-42-generic        4.10.0-42.46~16.04.1                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.10.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.13.0-26-generic        4.13.0-26.29~16.04.2                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.13.0-32-generic        4.13.0-32.35                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.13.0-36-generic        4.13.0-36.40                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.13.0-37-generic        4.13.0-37.42                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.13.0-38-generic        4.13.0-38.43                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.13.0-39-generic        4.13.0-39.44                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.13.0-41-generic        4.13.0-41.46                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic                        4.15.0.20.23                                amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
ii  linux-libc-dev:amd64                       4.15.0-20.21                                amd64        Linux Kernel Headers for development
ii  linux-modules-4.15.0-20-generic            4.15.0-20.21                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-20-generic      4.15.0-20.21                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-signed-image-4.10.0-28-generic       4.10.0-28.32~16.04.2                        amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-signed-image-4.10.0-42-generic       4.10.0-42.46~16.04.1                        amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-signed-image-4.13.0-26-generic       4.13.0-26.29~16.04.2                        amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-signed-image-4.13.0-32-generic       4.13.0-32.35                                amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-sound-base                           1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5                        all          base package for ALSA and OSS sound systems
ii  pptp-linux                                 1.9.0+ds-2                                  amd64        Point-to-Point Tunneling Protocol (PPTP) Client
ii  syslinux                                   3:6.03+dfsg1-2                              amd64        collection of bootloaders (DOS FAT and NTFS bootloader)
ii  syslinux-common                            3:6.03+dfsg1-2                              all          collection of bootloaders (common)
ii  syslinux-legacy                            2:3.63+dfsg-2ubuntu9                        amd64        Bootloader for Linux/i386 using MS-DOS floppies
ii  util-linux                                 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3                           amd64        miscellaneous system utilities
```

Comment: The output of `dpkg -l | grep linux` will be useful.

Comment: after running that command, there is a line which tells
 `ii  linux-modules-4.15.0-20-generic            4.15.0-20.21                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP`

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1037488/edit) your question above and add the requested information there.